# How do I use group by in DynamoDB?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using PHP with DynamoDB. I'm fetching some records by using 'scan'. I wanted to use Group By with this query just like in MySQL. Please help.

```
 $result = $client->scan([
            'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
                ':v1' => [
                    'S' => '2002',
                ]
            ],
            'FilterExpression' => 'userId = :v1',
            'TableName' => $this->table,
        ]);
        return $result;
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below: If you find yourself using `scan` and expect to be able to group items, DynamoDB may not be the tool you're looking for, or you haven't thought through your data model or table design.

Comment: Note also that scan is used to return the entire contents of a table, which consumes substantial read capacity units. In your example, you're filtering on `userId`, which suggests that what you really want to do is to `query` using `userId` as the hash key or from a secondary index using `userId` as the key. With your current code, a table with a million records would be returned, only for the client to throw away everything that doesn't match your filter expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `GROUP BY` in Dynamo DB. It is a NoSQL database, so it is not like SQL.

You can, however, use [HiveQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Querying.html) to query Dynamo in a SQL-like fashion.

Comment: Thanks @mkobit for the reply. I understand.
Can you please help me to use HiveQl with PHP. Any example.